# Running parallel queries in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a range query that we execute for dates between few months at a time. Though the kind of logic we have it executes faster when we use a date range of not more then single day. Plan is to execute the query with multiple day ranges and then calculate it at application level.

So I was wondering if anyone here can suggest how to run all these queries in parallel in MYSQL. Since if I do it in a transaction I think it will do one by one so if one query takes 1sec and we are sending 60 queries it will return back in 60 sec, which is not efficient. Any way of executing all 30 queries in parallel in one connection or do we need to create individual connections for all of them ?
Range can be like this

```
(date between '2010-02-25 ' and '2015-03-26')
(date between '2010-03-25 ' and '2015-04-26')
(date between '2010-04-25 ' and '2015-05-26')
(date between '2010-05-25' and '2015-06-26')
```

Comment: Are you using php?

Comment: If you manage to run them in parallel, the part where it's slow is retrieving data against which the match/queries must be made. Even if they are sequential or in parallel, they all still pull from the same data source - hard drive. The core of your problem lies in slow I/O device, which implies you should tune up your MySQL instance so it's quick in fetching the data it needs to work with.

Comment: i/o is not a problem here, i am using 4000k iops drive and mysql is fine tuned. Unless can you recommend certain parameter that can potentially be involved.

Comment: Well then, if you're saying it's fine tuned, without posting the config, table structure, indexes, output of `EXPLAIN` and output of profiling which are the usual essentials for spotting bottlenecks I guess that you must be correct in thinking executing it in parallel will yield performance, without establishing whether you're I/O or CPU bound. Good luck to you and all the best in getting this done the way you want!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PHP

You can use `multi_query` for this, see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

In general though, it doesn't really matter if you make 60 queries consecutive, at least if the database is hosted on the same server as the website that is. The response time will be so fast you won't notice a difference. If the database is hosted elsewhere than `multi_query` might be a good idea